# WooCommerce Scheduled Prices display the sale price instead of regular price after schedule ends

Tags: woocommerce, cron, schedule, price

I am setting a schedule start and end date for a product and set the regular and the sale price. 
Everything works good at this point, the price is displayed correctly
<strike>$10</strike> - $4

After the schedule date ends and and the cron updates the price it goes to $4. But the product price should be $10

This happens only with the cron from what I see, because if I go and edit the end schedule date to a different date it kind of resets and works as expected.

I tried to delete all transients, doesn't help.

Comment: Honestly, you should open a ticket with Woocommerce over this.

Comment: you would think this is a common think and if this would be a bug it would be patched a long time ago, but since there is not too much people complaining about this issue it might be something from my side, but I don't know what exactly... I will do that right now anyway.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, if anyone has more information about this bug, I would appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my CRON, it wasn't firing.

Comment: That would do it!